# Random lag on a stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my application, I use stored procedure to get a list of data, the procedure take no more than 2s directly from SSMS, and using entity framework in the application, it's quite quick too. But After something like 1 week, the time use to execute the stored procedure with entity framework became more than 20s, with timeout sometimes. 
I was trying to fix this issue when, for no reason, the speed return to 2s max. Finally, now, the time has increased again. This inconsistancy is a problem, how should I resolve this issue ?

To solve this issue, I tried a IISReset, I didn't see a lot of amelioration and this is not a durable solution anyway. The delay dropped first when I was modifying the names of the alias used in the procstock. Is there something with the executing plan cache ?

db.ps_myProcStock(id).ToList()

Comment: Hi Uranne, to give anyone a chance to reply, we need ore info. First of all, if its the SP that is taking longer, then my bet would be that it's on the SQL server you need to look to find the problem. Performance issues are caused by a host of factors, and until you can isolate each one it's impossible to reply.

I would suggest looking at the SP in isolation, perhaps use query store, or look at othe internals when the SP is slow (https://www.sqlshack.com/use-cases-for-query-store-in-sql-server/)

Comment: The problem is not on the perf of the SP. The SP is quick when executed directly with SSMS (less than 2s) And using EF, it is quick too, it first, but after a random amount of time, it become slow -only using EF- (more than 20s).

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Thank you for the document, it will help me. The issues seems solved with a teammate, it was inside the SP and not linked directly to the execution. Sorry ~